# VS2015 C# string.Format throws error when using escaped curly brackets

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a long JSON string which naturally contains lots of curly brackets.  I escaped the curly brackets using two opening and closing brackets for each (as is the recommendation in some previous posts on stackoverflow).  I still get the error:

> System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format.

Here's a shortened example:

```
var json = string.Format($@"{{""{data.GraphId}""}}");
```

Has anything changed how format works? 
What is the correct way to escape curly brackets now?

Comment: why you didn't use a JSON library?

Comment: Why are you mixing `string.Format` with interpolated strings (the `$` before the string)?  The whole idea of interpolated strings is to replace `string.Format` so the code is less verbose.

Comment: No `string.Format` needed: `var json = $"{{{data.GraphId}}}";`, with quotes: `$"\"{{{data.GraphId}}}\""`

Comment: @galister There is no issue with mixing interpolation and verbatim, just mixing `string.Format` and interpolation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String interpolation is just turned into a call to `string.Format`.  So the string you pass to `string.Format` will be changed from

```
$@"{{""{data.GraphId}""}}"
```

to something like the following

```
string.Format(@"{{""{0}""}}", data.GraphId)
```

So your code is equivalent to

```
string.Format(string.Format(@"{{""{0}""}}", data.GrpahId));
```

Once the inner `string.Format` is done it would look like the following assuming `data.GrpahId` is say 5

```
string.Format(@"{""5""}");
```

So now you see that your previously delimited curly brackets are no longer delimited.  The solution is to not use interpolated strings in `string.Format`, or if you do for some reason you have to double up the curly braces.

On another note if you're dealing with Json you should just use a library rather than attempting to format it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.  The structure is ld+json and complex, not sure if using a library would make it easier.  Any recommendations?

Comment: I've used Json.Net. It may take a some work to deal with your complex situation, but it's likely less than building the Json yourself.